# MariaDB restore InnoDB db from file system files

Tags: innodb, restore, mariadb

How can I restore a InnoDB database from filesystem files (FRM/IBD)? I cannot run db service from that system, so I tought to move its file to another Windows machine but I don't know if is there any procedure to follow in this case.

Comment: All files in the tree.

Comment: MariaDB loads db only by filesystem, nothing else?

Comment: True.  One file is not in the tree -- `my.cnf`.